# Restrict typing In Text Box from keyboard but enable for bar-code readers

Tags: c#, .net

I have an application which is just reading bar-code data and save it. But before saving i just want to restrict user to change the scanned data.

If i make text box read only or enabled false then reader also unable to assign scanned data in text box. I have also tried for Events like Key Press, Key Up, Key Down etc.

Comment: Is it WinForms, or WPF, or something different altogether? Depending on the system, different solutions may be required. Either way, setting Text property directly worked for me in a test WPF application, for IsReadOnly="True" and IsEnabled="False" text boxes alike.

Comment: This is a good one. I've been wondering about it too. Depending on the bar code you might be able to detect 'simple' text input, but maybe one can't..

Comment: I just did a few tests in the keypress event and found manual keystrokes to be almost all be > 20ms while scanner codes come in always <15 ms on my machine.. So that could indeed help.